# Error: conncet etimedout aws rds with mysql

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-rds, inbound-security-rule

Trying to connect mysql in ubuntu with remote rds mysql(Antares Sql) but facing etimedout error.
Tried adding inbound rule aswell

> All traffic ipv6

I am very new to aws. I used the default vpc

How shall I solve this problem and why is this Problem occurring?

Should I switch to windows?

**Edited**

I signed up as IAM user and selected rds

Chose *mysql* & *Free tire*

Db engine- *8.0.27*

Db instance class- *Burstable classes*

Storage info - kept it as fedault

Availability & durability - *Do not create a stand by instance*

Subnet Group : *default-vpc-05ff...add3*

Security group: *default*

Publicly accessible & port :*3306*

Then set my user name and passwors

(Vcp was the default vcp i dint creat any)

Ragion -*Singapore*

After the database is created i tried to connect it with my mysql workbench
It showes a timedout error
I added a new inbound rule according to internet solution

**Alltrafic and ipv6 anywhere**

But the problem din't go.

Comment: Is your RDS public?

Comment: Yes Sir @Marcin

Comment: I am trying this for like 1.5days now but couldn't figure out the problem.  @Marcin

Comment: You have to update your question with all network details of your RDS, an instance as well exact procedure you use to connect to the mysql.